# Как реализовать поиск в базе данных SQLITE через QT query?

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite

Язык c++.  Есть список компаний, необходимо реализовать поиск в бд SQLITE.

Метод обновления списка компаний (ListWidget) через цикл прохода по бд, он работает нормально.

```
ui->listWidget->clear();
DataBase::openDataBase();
QSqlQuery query("SELECT * FROM clients");
QSqlRecord rec = query.record();
while (query.next()){
    companyName = query.value(rec.indexOf("companyName")).toString();
    ui->listWidget->addItem(companyName);
}
```

Добавил LineEdit, и по изменению LineEdit текст является объектом для поиска

```
 DataBase::openDataBase();
if (arg1 == "") {
    listWidgetUpdate(); //Если пустое поле
} else{
    ui->listWidget->clear();
    QSqlQuery query("SELECT * FROM clients WHERE companyName LIKE '%:search%';");
    query.bindValue(":search", arg1);
    QSqlRecord rec = query.record();
    while (query.next()){
        companyName = query.value(rec.indexOf("companyName")).toString();
        ui->listWidget->addItem(companyName);
    }
}
```

Если поле пустое - выводятся компании из бд, но стоит ввести что угодно иное - ListWidget пустует. Думаю, ошибка в оформлении query запроса, но понять что-то не могу, подскажите знатоки)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообщем, ошибку выдавало " Parameter count mismatch ", причем выдавало её именно при поисковом запросе с %. Тут ответа не дождался, сделал костыль - новую переменную типа QString srch , и немного отредактировал запрос. Теперь всё заработало

```
QString srch = "%" + arg1 + "%"; //Новая переменная
if (arg1 == "") {
    listWidgetUpdate();
} else{
    ui->listWidget->clear();
    QSqlQuery query;
    query.prepare("SELECT * FROM clients WHERE companyName LIKE :search");
    query.bindValue(":search", srch);
    if(!query.exec()){
        qDebug() << query.lastError().text();
    } 
    QSqlRecord rec = query.record();
    while (query.next()){
        companyName = query.value(rec.indexOf("companyName")).toString();
        ui->listWidget->addItem(companyName);
    }
}
```